# Sum a column having text(interpreted as number dynamically) based on condition on another column

Tags: excel-formula

I need a help under below condition(simplified to save effort) in excel:

1. I have two columns containing string values i.e. Type and Status
2. I want the sum as a number in my output

   Type               Status

   -----             --------

   **Fixed            Yes**

   Floating            No

   **Fixed            Yes**

   Floating           Yes

   Fixed               No

   **Fixed            Yes**

   Floating            No

   ---

   Expected Output :: 3

   ---

**Condition:**

If Type column is "Fixed" and corresponding "Status" column is "Yes"
Then add plus 1 to the total

In this case, I have 3 cases where Type is "Fixed" and "Status" is "Yes", hence the expected output is 3.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Use [COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,"Fixed",$B$2:$B$8,"Yes")
```

[image]